# Проблема с setBounds

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Очень странно отрабатывает следующий код в Yandex Maps API:

`myMap.setBounds([[55.7526430212, 37.642848506], [55.7551600392, 37.5976318264]], { checkZoomRange: true });`

Обе точки в центре Москвы, но при вызове данного кода карта уходит на минимальный зум (Вся карта Земли). Может у кого-то есть идеи, что здесь не так? Коордитаны слишком близкие?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Координаты для setBounds задаются как левый нижний угол и правый верхний.
Правильным будет задавать точки так:

```
myMap.setBounds([[55.7526430212, 37.5976318264], [55.7551600392, 37.642848506]], { checkZoomRange: true });
```

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ. Т.е. перед выполнением кода нужно будет каждый раз сравнивать/сортировать коордитаны?

Comment: Я думал вы эти координаты сами придумали. Если вы их получаете где-то в апи, то скорее вы что-то делаете неправильно. Методом тыка я предположу что вы хотите выставить баундс добавленных меток? Если это так, то нужно сделать так:  myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds()); Если нет, то нужно больше информации, баундс чего вы хотите выставить. Лучше с кодом который вы написали.

Comment: Да у меня есть набор меток, но bounds нужно вычислить только для некоторых по фильтру. Решил свою проблемы следующим способом. 

Фильтрую объекты и записываю координаты в массив `needCoords`. Вычисляю bounds по всем координатам из массива и отправляю на карту: `myMap.setBounds(ymaps.util.bounds.fromPoints(needCoords));`

Comment: Отличное решение!) Или это то решение которое не работает?

Comment: Это рабочее решение.